# Ubuntu 20.04: не устанавливается Qt5 (qt5-default), конфликт пакетов mesa-common-dev и существующего mesa-common-dri

Tags: ubuntu, qt5, opengl

В конечном итоге все сводится к конфликту пакетов libgl-dev более новой версии который уже существует в системе и тем который содержится в требуемых пакетах qt5-default mesa-common-dev и т д

существующе пакеты libgl принадлежат пакету mesa-common-dri

С какой стороны подойти чтобы разобраться во всей этой пакетной каше?

Comment: вам на askubuntu

Comment: *С какой стороны подойти чтобы разобраться во всей этой пакетной каше?* — для начала наведите порядок в той каше, которую создали, наподключав всяких разных репозиториев.

Comment: так вся линукс вселенная состоит из "всяких разных репозиториев, всяких разных дистрибутивов, всяких разных ядер и всяких разных пакетных менеджеров" когда бы я их там сортировал бы мне завтра на работу...